# Unable to install python 3.7 library

Tags: libraries, python3, pip

I installed Python 3.7 (64 bit).
I have download the library pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

I'm trying to install it with the command below :

```
C:\Users\linus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip install pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl -f ./ --no-index
```

It does not work, it failed with error :

> ERROR: pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel
>   on this platform.

I tried with this one and same error.
numpy-1.16.4-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl

Could you help please.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the `.whl` files [downloadable here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas), `cp27` stands for Python 2.7. You can't install them with a Python 3.x distribution.

You need to download the ones available with `cp37`.

For example: `pandas‑0.24.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try installing directly from cmd with this command:

pip install pandas

it will install the latest and compatible version of pandas to python.